# QUnit multiple scripts in one page but no interaction between them

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, global-variables, qunit, atomic

I'm very new to unit testing (this is my first day working with QUnit and I've never worked with anything other testng system before), and I'm a bit unclear on how to test stuff from multiple script files in one QUnit page without letting the scripts interact with each other. What I mean is, say, if I have `script1.js`, and it calls `hello()`, and `hello()` is defined in `script2.js`, how can I run a unit test on `script1.js` to make sure it calls `hello()`, but mock the output of `hello()` so that it's a true unit test, and then run `script2.js`'s `hello()`.

Basically, how am I supposed to hide one script's global variables and functions from another script in a single QUnit page?

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on how the various script files are organized as well as the system as a whole. If you were using Angular, for example, then you are able to inject dependencies when you include a module in another script file. There are tools for mocking out things and "spying" on function calls such as [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), but it still depends heavily on how your code is organized.

For the sake of argument, let's say the two files look like so, and we'll ignore the design pattern (although you should seriously be considering that)...

```
// File A:
window.greeting = function() {
    var world = hello();
    return 'hello ' + world;
}

// File B:
window.hello = function() {
    // possibly lots of code to determine what to return...
    var value = 'foobar';
    return value;
}
```

The `hello()` function could just as easily return any other value based on the state of the system, user input, etc. For our case it doesn't, and what we want to do is mock out File B's code so that we don't have to test what it is doing, just that it gives back a string. **We could (and should) do this with a proper mocking/dependency injection library.** However, just to give you a sense of the minimal setup you could do, and to see the general approach, here's our QUnit test file:

```
var _hello;
QUnit.module('File A', {
  setup: function() {
    _hello = window.hello; // hold onto the old value
   // now we mock out hello()
    window.hello = function() {
      window.hello.called++;  // track calls to it
      return 'world'; // return our static value
    }
    window.hello.called = 0;
  },
  teardown: function() {
    // put the old one back
    window.hello = _hello || window.hello;
  }
});

QUnit.test('Ensure greeting is correct', function(assert) {
  var result = greeting();
  assert.equal(window.hello.called, 1, 'hello should be called only once');
  assert.equal(result, 'hello world', 'The greeting call should be "hello world"');
});
```

And if you want to see it running, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpq316eg/1/) for you. As I said, this is a simple example to show you how you *could* do this, but you should look into proper code organization (think AMD modules, require, Angular, Ember, things like this) and a proper mocking library.

Comment: Ok, so would a mocking library (sinon.js seems to fit my needs) override the functions defined by other files? So, if in file 2, I have the `hello()` function, but then I use sinon.js to mock out and create a "fake" `hello()` function, when I call `hello()` in file 1, will it call the fake hello or will it call the hello that is defined in file 2?

Comment: Again, this is all about how your code is written and organized. Sinon can create a "spy" for the `hello()` function (but not mock it out) with very little effort, but creating a true "mock" of the function requires the ability to inject that mock into your first script some how. But like I said, this entirely depends on how your code is written. If you are only using global functions, then you really don't have many options other than my example above.